# Is it "me" or "my" in this sentence? And why?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, gerunds, possessives

1. He was pretty emphatic about **me** leaving.
2. He was pretty emphatic about **my** leaving.

Which is correct, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purist would say: His emphasis was about an act of leaving.  What act of leaving?  My act.  Therefore, *my leaving*.

But “me leaving” is also very common, and can (at least sometimes) be defended by an alternate analysis: He was emphatic about me, and the *leaving* modifies *me*.  Then it must be a participle, rather than a gerund as in my first version.

Comment: "My leaving" and "me leaving" are both subordinate clauses with "my/ me" as subject and "leaving" as the predicate verb phrase. There's no semantic difference between the two, other than the fact that genitive "my" is more formal then accusative "me".

Comment: They are more like noun phrases than like clauses.

Comment: An NP has a noun as head, while a clause has a verb as head. "My/me leaving" has the verb "leaving" as head and thus is clause. It has nothing to do with possession, as in "my book", which would be an NP.

Comment: *my leaving* has more to do with possession than *my neighbor*.  How is it not a noun phrase?  Is a gerund not a noun? — The head of *me leaving* is *me*, just as the head of *a duck carrying a flag* is *duck*.

Comment: Why should genitive "my leaving" be an NP when "me leaving" is clearly a clause? The difference is surely just one of formality, with "leaving" being a verb in both cases.  There are several grammatical reasons why "my" is subject, not head of an NP, e.g. it must always be in absolute initial position. We can't say *He was about my leaving pretty emphatic". Note also that we can add a direct object, as in "He was pretty emphatic about my/me leaving him". You need to catch up with modern scholarly grammar, which has moved on a long was since the days when "my leaving" was considered an NP!

Comment: I would recommend not **opening** with an assumption that the other party agrees with your conclusion (that *me leaving* is “clearly” a clause despite not containing a finite verb).  – Tell me more about this absolute initial position.  Would you say “He was about baseball very serious”?  I certainly would not; is that evidence that *baseball* is not a noun?

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *He was pretty emphatic about* [*me leaving*].
>
> [2] *He was pretty emphatic about* [*my leaving*].

They are both correct and have the same meaning. "My leaving" and "me leaving" are both subordinate participial clauses with "my/me" as subject and "leaving" as the predicate verb phrase.

The only difference is that genitive "my" is more formal than accusative "me".