# Is it natural to say 'me not doing something' here?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, gerunds

Suppose Alice liked drawing and considered taking a related career path. When Alice found out she might not be talented enough and said she might quit, Bob encouraged her and told her that he wants her to keep drawing. (He always hopes she can pursue her dream.) Years later, when Alice'd quit for a year, she said to Bob,

> I kinda figured you'd gotten over it by now... **Me not drawing anymore**.

Is the construction 'me not drawing anymore' idiomatic here? When talk about others, is it natural to say things like, 'you not doing something', 'Jane not doing something', or '**him** not doing something'?

Comment: What about this structure makes you think it's not correct? I'll address my answer to that issue.

Comment: @gotube What I learnt from grammar books is 'my' should be used instead of 'me'.

Comment: Check [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328177/is-it-me-or-my-in-this-sentence-and-why).

Comment: Your grammar book may have said to use "my" because that's more formal, but I doubt it said "me" is wrong. If it did, then the book is either wrong or *prescriptivist*, which is just wrong in a different way.

Comment: What's the context for this? One possibility is that ‘Me not drawing anymore’ is baby talk: intentionally (and childishly) bad grammar, intended to sound like a young child. — Also, ‘anymore’ is not a standard English word; it should be ‘any more’.

Comment: @gidds Speakers are adults. For any more, see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/any-more-or-anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more usual,. at least in my experience, to use a possessive form: "*My not drawing anymore*" rather than "*Me not drawing anymore*". This also works with other subjects, such as "*Jane's not drawing anymore*" althogh thbere thenon-possesive form is more common, I think.

Another point: I, at least, would be more inclined to use "any more" than "anymore".

Yet another: The expression "*when Alice've quit*" is not a usual contraction for "when Alice had quit".